# command object validation strange behaviour

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I have the following command class:

```
class BookmakerCommand {
    Bookmaker bookmaker
    CommonsMultipartFile logotype

        logotype validator: { val, obj ->
            def logoImage = ImageIO.read(val.getInputStream())
            if (logoImage.width > 500 || logoImage.height > 500) {
                obj.errors.reject('logotype.invalid', 'bookmaker.logo.invalid.format')
            }
        }
}
```

where logotype is an image. As you can see in case if width or height has invalid size logotype field should be rejected. I want this error to appear in top of the page and using such construction for this purpose:

```
    <g:hasErrors bean="${command}">
        <ul class="errors" role="alert">
            <g:eachError bean="${command}" var="error">
                <li <g:if test="${error in org.springframework.validation.FieldError}">data-field-id="${error.field}"</g:if>><g:message error="${error}"/></li>
            </g:eachError>
        </ul>
    </g:hasErrors>
```

In case if some of bookmaker's fields is not valid this construction shows corresponding errors but it doesn't when logotype is not valid. I tried to debug and found out that this line:

```
obj.errors.reject('logotype.invalid', 'bookmaker.logo.invalid.format')
```

actually doesn't add error to command object because errors still have 0 size. What I'm doing wrong?
Thank you!

UPDATE:

I debuged one more time and found out that I was not completely right about this line:

```
obj.errors.reject('logotype.invalid', 'bookmaker.logo.invalid.format')
```

debugging within the validator code shows that this line adds the corresponding error to command object but error dissapears just after exiting validator code and going to back to controller. So I start debugging from this piece of code:

```
   if (!command.validate()) {
       ...
      }
```

debug goes to validator code:

```
logotype validator: { val, obj ->
                def logoImage = ImageIO.read(val.getInputStream())
                if (logoImage.width > 500 || logoImage.height > 500) {
                    obj.errors.reject('logotype.invalid', 'bookmaker.logo.invalid.format')
                }
            }
```

after that obj (which is command object) contains error ('bookmaker.logo.invalid.format') but when debug continues and goes to

```
   if (!command.validate()) {
       >> HERE
      }
```

command.errors becomes empty again. 
Very strange :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you shouldn't call `errors.reject()` in your validator. Instead, you must return `false` or error code:

```
logotype validator: { val, obj ->
   def logoImage = ImageIO.read(val.getInputStream())
   logoImage.width > 500 || logoImage.height > 500 ? 'bookmaker.logo.invalid.format' : true
}
```

Comment: would this work if I want to backlight corresponding field on the page? I mean something like this:
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: command, field: 'logotype', 'error')} ">
    <input type="file" name="logotype" id="logotype"/>
</div>

Comment: sure it would! the ref-doc states that and this is exactly how the whole validation should work

Comment: Would it work if I want to show multiple error messages for the same field. I mean if I have two constraints for the image - it should have size no bigger than some size and in the same time it should have corresponding format (jpg for instance). And if user uploads image with wrong size and format would it show two error messages or one? Thank you :-)

Comment: `g.eachError` tag accepts afield attribute. that means, that `<g:eachError bean="${book}" field="title">` prints out all errors for the given field

Comment: yes, but it seems to me that if for instance write 
boolean a = true, b = true;
if(a) {
'bookmaker.logo.invalid.format'
}

if(b) {
'bookmaker.logo.invalid.format'
}

then only one of two errors will be printed. Can you please give a hint how to push first message and second messages in case if both a and b are true?

Comment: in general you shouldn't show more than 1 error per field, otherwise the user would go crazy. The validator should return the errors (if many) as soon as it finds it. If you desperately want to show all possible errors for 1 field, you can call `obj.errors.reject()` in your controller code